# Make EnterpriseLibrary use the UnityContainer created through UnityBootstrapper

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

My application subclasses UnityBootstrapper which creates the default UnityContainer.

We are also using EnterpriseLibrary and what to force it to use our unity container created in the bootstrapper and not create it's own.

Is this an acceptable practice? Our reasoning is that we want to be able to access caches (we have multiple) created via injection to our classes without directly having to reference the enterprise library.

I've seen different things from using UnityContainerConfigurator and AddNewExtension() as well as just setting EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference and which is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using an explicitly instantiated container is perfectly acceptable.  Enterprise Library is designed to allow you to switch and use other dependency injection frameworks instead of Unity or you can BYOC (bring your own [Unity] container).

Basically, you just need to create the Enterprise Library extension and add it to the container and then set the container as the service locator that Enterprise Library will use.

In this example I have an app.config with a CacheManager configured called "My Cache Manager":

```
EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension coreExtension = 
    new EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension();

container.AddExtension(coreExtension);

IServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = locator;

var cacheManager1 = container.Resolve<CacheManager>("My Cache Manager");

var cacheManager2 = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current
                        .GetInstance<CacheManager>("My Cache Manager");

Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(cacheManager1, cacheManager2));
```

Comment: thanks. It's pretty much what i thought, and what i was doing.

Comment: It seems that registering Current this way messes with Prism region management. Still trying to work this out.